# ThreeJS texture reversed

Tags: three.js

I'm new to threejs just doing a basic cube with a texture to the backside. I have words on colour sides to the texture. However the words come out mirrored like. How can I get them to come out correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can negatively scale your cube to undo the mirror effect, like this:

```
cube.scale.x = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1. Reverse or rotate your UV coordinates on each face on the cube until you get the desired result. This is easy since the UV coordinates of a cube are usually 0.0 and 1.0.
2. Use an image package to rotate the textures as you want them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem as you with regards to texturing a cube.

As I understand it all surfaces come out correct orientation except the backside. The way i got around this was to place the textures on the cube per face and then alter the UV mapping of the back face.

This solved the problem of the back face being oriented incorrectly and also as a result of UV mapping I am now able to put textures on irregular faces to like pyramids etc.

Here is the solution by changing the UV of the backface. Just replace the loaded texture with a local texture cut and paste into notepad and save as html file and your good to go.

```
 <html> 
 <head>

</head> <body> <script src="js/three.min.js"></script> <script> var
scene, camera, renderer; var geometry, material; var modarray=[];
var material=[]; var rotation=0; init(); animate(); function init() 
{


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, 100 );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    ///////////     // Camera//     ///////////
        camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 2, 

window.innerWidth / 2, 100 / 2, 100 / - 2, - 500, 1000 );
        camera.position.z = 2000;   camera.position.y = 0;  camera.position.x = 0;  scene= new THREE.Scene();
        geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );     geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );

    ///////////////////////////////     // Store Materials for blocks//
    /////////////////////////////// var bricks;         material[0] = new
THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: 

THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('10.png') } );

var basex=-455; //////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Vector array to hold where UV will be placed //
////////////////////////////////////////////////// bricks = [new
THREE.Vector2(1, 0), new THREE.Vector2(1, 1), new 

THREE.Vector2(0, 1), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0)];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////// // choose what
face this eccects from vertex array //  // in this case backside    
// // choose the orientation of the triangles         //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][10] = [ bricks[0], bricks[1], bricks[3]];
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][11] = [ bricks[1], bricks[2], bricks[3]];


        modarray[0] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material[0]);   modarray[1] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material[0]);

    modarray[0].position.x=basex;   modarray[0].position.z=1000;
    modarray[0].position.y=0;
        scene.add(modarray[0]);

    modarray[1].position.x=basex+65;    modarray[1].position.z=1000;
    modarray[1].position.y=0;
        scene.add(modarray[0]);     scene.add(modarray[1]);

    //////////  // LIGHT//  //////////  var light2 = new
THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);   light2.position.set(0,100,2000);
    scene.add(light2);


}


//////////////////// // Animation Loop // ///////////////////
function animate()  {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate ); var flag=0;

    for(n=0; n<2; n++)  {

            modarray[n].rotation.x=rotation;

    }       rotation+=0.03;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );


}

</script> <p>The cube on the left is with UV mapping to correct the
back surface.

The cube on the right is without the UV mapping.</p> </body>

</html>
```